# Bean data doesn't write to table via ORM/entityLoad()

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mach-ii

I'm trying to implement CF10 ORM to a current project but there seems to be a problem between my DAO and my table (11g).

I pass in a bean in the call to this DAO method:

```
<cffunction name="saveData" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="DataBean" />

    <cfset entitySave(arguments.DataBean)/>
</cffunction>
```

This should write it to the table. If I dump the arguments from inside this method the bean is populated, but nothing writes. There's no errors being thrown so nothing immediately obvious.

Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to call `EntityNew()` first before the save?

Comment: yeah all that stuff is working ok, one of the team might have sorted this though so any joy and I'll post it. Thanks for looking.

Comment: What do you have for ORM settings in Application.cfc? Try using `ORMFlush()` after the `entitySave()` call.